# Trouble with method inside of class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

We are having trouble getting the gettot() method to work in side of our game class. When it is called inside of our game as a whole it comes back with an error saying that we dont have the correct amount of inputs for the function to operate correctly. Currently the first iteration of the functions is commented out so we could get further in the project without it stopping our game every time that it runs.

this is the gettot method we are having issues with:

---

The purpose of this method is to get the total of the cards that a player or dealer has in their hand, if there is an ace, it decides whether or not it should be a 1 or an 11 depending on which gets it closer to 21 total points without going over.

```
def gettot(self,hand):
        total=0
        for x in self.hand:
            if x==Card('H','A'):
                b=total+x
                if b>21:
                    total+=1
                else:
                    total+=11
            if x==Card('D','A'):
                b=total+x
                if b>21:
                    total+=1
                else:
                    total+=11
            if x==Card('S','A'):
                b=total+x
                if b>21:
                    total+=1
                else:
                    total+=11
            if x==Card('C','A'):
                b=total+x #changed
                if b>21:
                    total+=1
                else:
                    total+=11
            else:
                total+=x
        return(total)

from random import*
#do we need to address anywhere that all face cards are worth 10?
class Card(object):
    def __init__(self,suit,number):
        self.number=number
        self.suit=suit
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s'%(self.number,self.suit)

class DeckofCards(object):
    def __init__(self,deck):
        self.deck=deck
        self.shuffledeck=self.shuffle()

    def shuffle(self):
        b=[]
        count=0
        while count<len(self.deck):
            a=randrange(0,len(self.deck))
            if a not in b:
                b.append(self.deck[a])
                count+=1
        return(b)

    def deal(self):
        if len(self.shuffledeck)>0:
            return(self.shuffledeck.pop(0))
        else:
            shuffle(self.deck) #need to refill deck
            return(self.shuffledeck.pop(0))
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self,name,hand,inout,money,score,bid):
        self.name=name
        self.hand=hand
        self.inout=inout
        self.money=money
        self.score=score
        self.bid=bid

    def __str__(self):
        x = self.name + ":\t"
        x += "Card(s):"
        for y in range(len(self.hand)):
            x +=self.hand[y].face + self.hand[y].suit + " "
        if (self.name != "dealer"):
            x += "\t Money: $" + str(self.money)
        return(x)

class Game(object):
    def __init__(self,deck, player):
        self.player=Player(player,[],True,100,0,0)
        self.dealer=Player("Dealer",[],True,100,0,0)
        self.deck=DeckofCards(deck)
        self.blackjack= False
    def blackjacksearch(self):
        if Game.gettot(self.player.hand)==21:#changed
            return True
        else:
            return False    
    def firstround(self):
        #self.player.inout=True#do we need this since this is above
        #self.player.hand=[]#do wee need this....
        #self.dealer.hand=[]#do we need this ....
        self.player.hand.append(DeckofCards.deal(self.deck))
        for card in self.player.hand:
            a=card
        print(self.player.name + ' ,you were dealt a '+str(a))
        self.dealer.hand.append(DeckofCards.deal(self.deck))
        for card in self.dealer.hand:
            a=card
        print('The Dealer has '+str(a))
        playerbid=int(input(self.player.name + ' how much would you like to bet? '))
        self.player.money-=playerbid
        self.player.bid=playerbid
    def playturn(self): #should this be changed to inout instead of hit.....we never use inout
        #for player in self.player:
        #    a=player
        #print(str(a))
        hit=input('Would you like to hit? ') #should input be in loop?
        while self.player.inout==True: #and self.blackjack!=True:#changed
            #print(self.player.name + ' , your hand has:' + str(self.player.hand)) #do we want to make this gettot? so it prints out the players total instead of a list....if we want it in a list we should print it with out brakets
            self.player.hand.append(DeckofCards.deal(self.deck))
            for card in self.player.hand:
                a=card
            print('The card that you just drew is: ' + str(a))            
            print(self.player.name + ' , your hand has:' + str([str(card) for card in self.player.hand]))
            #print(Game.gettot(self.player.hand)) 
            hit=input('Would you like to hit? ')
            if hit=='yes':
                (self.player.hand.append(DeckofCards.deal(self.deck)))#changed
                self.player.inout==True#
            else:
                (self.player.hand) #changed
                self.player.inout==False #changed
        if self.player.blackjack==True:
            print(self.player.name + " has blackjack ")
        if hit=='no':
            print (self.player.hand.gettot())
    def playdealer(self):
        while Game.gettot(self.dealer.hand)<17:#changed
            self.dealer.hand.append(DeckofCards.deal(self.deck))
            dealerhand=Game.gettot(self.dealer.hand) #changed
            print(dealerhand)
        if Game.gettot(self.dealer.hand)==21:#changed
            self.dealer.blackhjack=True
        dealerhand1=Game.gettot(self.dealer.hand)#changed
        print(dealerhand1)

    def gettot(self,hand):
        total=0
        for x in self.hand:
            if x==Card('H','A'):
                b=total+x
                if b>21:
                    total+=1
                else:
                    total+=11
            if x==Card('D','A'):
                b=total+x
                if b>21:
                    total+=1
                else:
                    total+=11
            if x==Card('S','A'):
                b=total+x
                if b>21:
                    total+=1
                else:
                    total+=11
            if x==Card('C','A'):
                b=total+x #changed
                if b>21:
                    total+=1
                else:
                    total+=11
            else:
                total+=x
        return(total)

    def playgame(self):
        play = "yes"
        while (play.lower() == "yes"):
            self.firstround()
            self.playturn()
            if self.player.blackjack == True:
                print(self.player.name + " got BLACKJACK! ")
                self.player.money += self.player.bid * 1.5
                print (self.player.name + " now has " + str(self.player.money))
                print("\n")
                self.player.inout = False
            if self.player.score > 21:
                print(self.player.name + " lost with a tot of " + str(self.player.score))
                self.player.money -= self.player.bid
                print (self.player.name + " now has " + str(self.player.money))
                print ("\n\n")
                self.player.inout = False
            self.playdealer()
            if self.dealer.blackjack == True:
                print("Dealer got blackjack, dealer wins\n")
                self.player.money -= self.player.bid
                print("Round\n")
                print("\t",self.dealer)
                print("\t",self.player)
                print("\t Dealer has " + str(self.dealer.score) + ", " + self.player.name + " has " + str(self.player.score))
            elif self.player.inout == True:
                print("Round\n")
                print("\t",self.dealer)
                print("\t",self.player)
                print("\n\t Dealer has " + str(self.dealer.score) + ", " + self.player.name + " has " + str(self.player.score))
                if self.dealer.score > 21:
                    print("\t Dealer lost with a total of " + str(self.dealer.score))
                    self.player.money += self.player.bid
                    print(self.player.name + " now has " + str(self.player.money))
                elif self.player.score > self.dealer.score:
                    print("\t" +self.player.name + " won with a total of " + str(self.player.score))
                    self.player.money += self.player.bid
                    print("\t"+self.player.name + " now has " + str(self.player.money))
                else:
                    print("\t Dealer won with a total of " + str(self.dealer.score))
                    self.player.money -= self.player.bid
                    print("\t"+self.player.name + " now has " + str(self.player.money))
            else:
                print("Round")
                print("\t",self.dealer)
                print("\t",self.player)
                if self.player.blackjack == False:
                    print("\t "+ self.player.name + " lost" )
                else:
                    print("\t "+self.player.name + " Won!")

            if self.player.money <= 0:
                print(self.player.name + " out of money - out of game ")
                play = "no"
            else:
                play = input("\nAnother round? ")
                print("\n\n")
        print("\nGame over. ")
        print(self.player.name + " ended with " + str(self.player.money) + " dollars.\n")
        print("Thanks for playing.  Come back soon!")



ls= [Card('H','A'),Card('H','2'),Card('H','3'),Card('H','4'),Card('H','5'),Card('H','6'),Card('H','7'),Card('H','8'),Card('H','9'),Card('H','10'),
Card('H','J'),Card('H','Q'),Card('H','K'),
Card('S','A'),Card('S','2'),Card('S','3'),Card('S','4'),Card('S','5'),
Card('S','6'),Card('S','7'),Card('S','8'),Card('S','9'),Card('S','10'),
Card('S','J'),Card('S','Q'),Card('S','K'),
Card('C','A'),Card('C','2'),Card('C','3'),Card('C','4'),Card('C','5'),
Card('C','6'),Card('C','7'),Card('C','8'),Card('C','9'),Card('C','10'),
Card('C','J'),Card('C','Q'),Card('C','K'),
Card('D','A'),Card('D','2'),Card('D','3'),Card('D','4'),Card('D','5'),
Card('D','6'),Card('D','7'),Card('D','8'),Card('D','9'),Card('D','10'),
Card('D','J'),Card('D','Q'),Card('D','K')]


def main():
    x = input("Player's name? ")
    blackjack = Game(ls,x)
    blackjack.playgame()
main()
```

Comment: You need to describe what the problem is.  Don't just say "it doesn't work".  What does it do that you don't want it to do?

Comment: I just tried to add some info but I am actually unsure of what the issue is

Comment: gettot() takes two arguments: `self`, and `hand`. `hand` never gets used, and when you call the function you only pass one argument (`self.dealer.hand`). Also, it appears to be a function defined outside of a class, so it really makes no sense for it to have a `self` argument in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR but one thing I noticed is this: `x==Card('H','A')`.

This won’t work unless you define your `Card` type to handle equality comparisons in a useful way. By default it will check if they are both the same objects, and as you create a new card, it won’t be the same object as `x`.

```
class Card(object):
    # ...
    def __eq__ (self, other):
        return self.number == other.number and self.suit == other.suit
```

Also, this: `b=total+x`. If `x` is a Card object, how do you imagine it being added to a number? You have to define this, or do `b = total + x.number` instead.

Another thing is that you define `gettot` to take a `hand` parameter, but in the function, you iterate over `self.hand`. So any other hand you pass to the function is quietly ignored and `self.hand` is used instead.

Also this:

```
def blackjacksearch(self):
    if Game.gettot(self.player.hand)==21:
    # ...
```

This method belongs to the Game type; and it’s an instance method (taking a `self` parameter). But you actually call it as a static method from the `Game` type not an instance. It should be something like `self.gettot()` instead (you can leave out the parameter as per above).

You do the same at some other places too, trying to call instance methods by using `TypeName.method`. You need to have objects you call them on.

I think you can make your `gettot` method a lot shorter too:

```
def gettot(self,hand):
    total=0
    for x in self.hand:
        if x.number == 'A':
            if total + 11 > 21:
                total += 1
            else:
                total += 11
        elif x.number == 'J' or x.number == 'Q' or x.number == 'K':
            pass # what to do with these?
        else:
            total += x.number
    return(total)
```

---

Rewriting some parts of your code:

```
class Card (object):
    def __init__ (self, suit, number):
        self.suit = suit
        self.number = number

    def getValue (self):
        if self.number in ('J', 'Q', 'K'):
            return 10
        elif self.number == 'A':
            return 11
        else
            return int(self.number)

    def isAce (self):
        return self.number == 'A'

    def __eq__ (self, other):
        return self.suit == other.suit and self.number == other.number

    def __str__ (self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.number,self.suit)

class DeckOfCards (object):
    def __init__ (self, deck):
        self.fullDeck = deck
        self.shuffle()

    def shuffle (self):
        self.deck = self.fullDeck[:] # copy the full deck
        random.shuffle(self.deck)

    def deal (self):
        if not len(self.deck): # need to refill deck
            self.shuffle()
        return self.deck.pop(0)

ls = []
for suit in ('H', 'S', 'C', 'D'):
    for number in ('A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K'):
        ls.append(Card(suit, number))
```

Your `gettot` method should belong to a player, and would look like this:

```
def gettot(self):
    total = 0
    for card in self.hand:
        if card.isAce() and total > 10:
            total += 1
        else:
            total += card.getValue()
    return total
```

Comment: When I added what you suggested, this is what I got. `Traceback (most recent call last):
........
  File "C:\Users\Ian\Downloads\proj2.1.py", line 55, in __init__
    self.deck=DeckofCards(deck)
  File "C:\Users\Ian\Downloads\proj2.1.py", line 15, in __init__
    self.shuffledeck=self.shuffle()
  File "C:\Users\Ian\Downloads\proj2.1.py", line 22, in shuffle
    if a not in b:
  File "C:\Users\Ian\Downloads\proj2.1.py", line 10, in __eq__
    return self.number == other.number and self.suit == other.suit
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'number'`

Comment: @TammyLogger That’s because you are comparing a number with a card object, you are constantly mixing up the types treating cards as numbers you can add to numbers or check if a number is in a list of cards (that’s where your error comes from: `if a not in b` for a list of cards `b` and an int `a` in the `shuffle` method).

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous problems

1. I would add a function to Card that asks if it is an Ace. That will work better then constructing a bunch and seeing if they are equal.
2. You are using `==` instead of `=` for some of your assignments.  `==` is for comparison. `=` is for assignment.
3. don't say `inout == True`  just say `inout` (since inout is a bool already)
4. you keep poping off the deck.  When you run out you shuffle it again, but at this point it has nothing in it.
5. at the top of `gettot` you are referencing `self.hand`, but `self` doesnt have a `hand` it should just be `hand` as it is passed into `gettot`.
6. `player.blackjack` is never defined but I would add a check there for if gettot == 21, and move gettot to a modual function for now
7. `self.player.hand.gettot()` should be `gettot(self.player.hand)`
8. you are `total+=x` where total is an int and x is a Card, you cant add those unless you define how to add an int to a Card. I would just add to Card a get_value function for now to get the face value. (you could handle face cards being value of 10 here too) then use `total += x.get_value()`
9. you also want to adjust for aces at the end of gettot, otherwise you don't know if you are going to be over 21.  ie. what happends if the first card in your hand is an ace?

example:

```
class Card(object):
    def __init__(self,suit,number):
        self.number=number
        self.suit=suit

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s'%(self.number,self.suit)

    def get_value(self):
        if self.number == 'A':
            return 11
        if self.number in 'JQK':
            return 10
        return int(self.number)

    def is_ace(self):
        return self.number == 'A'


def gettot(hand):
    total = 0
    aces = 0
    for x in hand:
        if x.is_ace():
            aces += 1
        total += x.get_value()
    while aces and total > 21:
        aces -= 1
        total -= 10
    return total
```

That should get you started, just keep debugging

Answer (score 0):

You define `gettot()` to take two arguments: self, and hand. Then you never use `hand`, and when you call the function you only pass one argument (self.dealer.hand).

Eliminate the `self` argument (which makes no sense anyway, since it's a function defined outside of a class), and replace the `for x in self.hand` line with `for x in hand`.  Even better, make the function a method of the Player object.